# How should I understand $\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(x)$?

Tags: reference-request, notation, partial-differential-equations

The formula is from the first paragraph in the paper "[Second Kind Integral Equation Formulation of Stokes' Flows Past a Particle of Arbitrary Shape](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2101562)" by Power and Miranda:

> ... the governing equations for the auxiliary perturbed fluid velocity $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and pressure $p$ can be approximated by the creeping motion and continuity equations
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(x)\\
> &\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}(x)=0
> \end{align}
> $$

Here are my **questions**:

- How should I understand the first formula? Is the Einstein summation convention applied here, i.e., 
  $$
  \sum_j\frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(x)?
  $$
- Is there any reference for the derivation of the first formula? (I don't find any in the paper.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeping_motion

Einstein summation convention is indeed implied.  In other words, the equation can be written as
$$
\nabla ^2\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{\nabla}p.
$$

As for the derivation, according to the article, it follows directly from the Navier-Stokes equations, but as I don't know what they mean by ". . . the inertial forces are assumed to be negligible . . .", I'm afraid I can't explain this.

Comment: @JonathanGleason, Thanks for your comment. It is the answer I'm looking for. When I read your $\nabla^2 v=\nabla p$, things are clear to me. May I suggest you to write it down as an answer?

Comment: The second formula in the question, I think, means $\nabla\cdot v=0$, instead of $\nabla v=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Wikipedia article [Creeping Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeping_motion).

Einstein summation convention is indeed implied. In other words, the equation can be written as $\nabla ^2\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{\nabla}p$.

As for the derivation, according to the article, it follows directly from the Navier-Stokes equations, but as I don't know what they mean by ". . . the inertial forces are assumed to be negligible . . .", so I'm afraid I can't explain this, although perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) will help.

Note:  The original reason I did not want to post this as an answer was because I don't know how to completely answer your second point.  In any case, if you are happy with this answer, then I am certainly happy to post it as one :).

Comment: The "inertial forces" neglected in the Stokes equation are simply the time derivative terms. Navier Stokes has the form "Forces = mass* acceleration" as in classical mechanics, but formulated for a fluid element and "mass * acceleration" is what they call inertial forces. The reason this is neglected is that the limit of Reynolds number $ \to \infty$ is taken. Another way of deriving this equation is by minimizing the dissipation $\int_V (\partial_i v_j) (\partial_i v_j) \mathrm{d}V$ for an incompressible flow.